# Assigning unique_ptr to object

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Noobie here trying to understand smart pointers. Why am I allowed to do this:

```
    int *p1;
    int var1 = 1;
    p1 = &var1;
```

but not this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2;
    int var2 = 2;
    p2 = &var2;
```

I get *No viable overloaded '='* on the last line. Is there any way to create a unique_ptr without assigning it, create an int object, and THEN assign the unique_ptr to that object?

Comment: Because `std::unique_ptr` is a class template which aims to avoid issues that can potentially be caused by such direct assignment. And assigning the address of an object with automatic storage duration to `std::unique_ptr` is definitely a bug

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` owns the pointer it wraps.  Allowing `p2 = &var2;` would break that since `&var2` is not a pointer that can be owned.

Comment: `p2 = std::make_unique<int>(var2);`

Comment: The key semantic of `unique_ptr` is **unique**.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see, is it possible to access the wrapped pointer from the unique pointer? Or how do I access the address of the variable (suppose I can't use ```&var2``` directly). ```p2``` seem to hold a different address than ```&var2```.

Comment: @elvira.granqvist You can access the wrapped pointer by calling `get` on the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @NathanOliver if I print ```p2.get()``` I still get a different address than if I print ```&var2```

Comment: @elvira.granqvist If you did `p2 = std::make_unique<int>(var2);`, then of course it has a different address.  `make_unique` creates a new object and returns a `unique_ptr` that owns that object.  It will have no connection to `var2` except that it will have the same value.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah ok, so there is no way to retrieve the address of a variable through a unique pointer?

Comment: You can't assign the address of a variable to a unique_ptr, so no you can't use it like in your first example.

Comment: @NathanOliver great, then I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> [Why am I not allowed to do this]:
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<int> p2;
> int var2 = 2;
> p2 = &var2;
> ```

Because a unique pointer takes ownership of the bare pointer that it wraps, and when the unique pointer is destroyed, it will invoke the deleter on that pointer. You must never delete pointers to objects in automatic storage. That's a language rule, and if you don't follow the rule, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Hence, you must never transfer the ownership of a pointer to automatic (nor static, nor thread local) object to a smart pointer. You can never have ownership of such variables, so such ownership isn't yours to transfer.

> Is there any way to create a unique_ptr without assigning it, create an int object, and THEN assign the unique_ptr to that object?

Yes. Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p2;
p2 = std::make_unique<int>(2);
```

P.S. A dynamically allocating `int` is probably rarely useful.